# displays data with a different sign from the database

Tags: php, database, unique

coding to show the lights that are unlike any other

if the data in the database has a value of 1 then the character will appear glowing lights whereas if the data in the database has a value of 0 is the emerging light is not glowing.

illustrations like the link below picture:

[image: pic]

help me please

Comment: Welcome to SO, @dani warrior. Can you give us a code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, here's one  approach:

```php
<img src="/path/to/images/<?= $data ? 'img1.png' : 'img0.png' ?>" ... />
```

You could also write a function that outputs different images depending on the value, that's completely up to you. You have to give us some code if you want a more precise answer. Also, I don't know how you are generating your table. $data is the value of the column you described.

Answer (score 0):

in your SQL query you can have `SELECT CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as someParameter FROM ...`

and then in your code check for the someParameter value and display different image according to its value.

Look at the [documentations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) for more information (I'm assuming you're using mysql)